# Why is ufw firewall not starting automatically?

Tags: firewall

ufw has been starting automatically for as long as I've had it over a year.  Now I have to go in at startup and manually turn it on before I can connect to my server.
I use ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1356626/edit) your question and add what version of Ubuntu you are running and the output of `systemctl list-unit-files | grep ufw`.  Thank you!

Comment: is the service ufw enable?

Comment: The service will only enable if I log in and

Comment: I entered "systemctl list-unit-files | grep ufw" in the terminal and it reads enabled.